# How can i resolve this issue that i am having when creating a custom query method in my repository using spring jpa

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Hello im trying to create a custom query method in my repository but when i run my application i get this error

```
 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionRepo' defined in com.base.BaseDependencies.Repository.TransactionRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.base.BaseDependencies.Repository.TransactionRepo.findByFromAccount(com.base.BaseDependencies.Models.Account); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.base.BaseDependencies.Repository.TransactionRepo.findByFromAccount(com.base.BaseDependencies.Models.Account)! No property 'fromAccount' found for type 'Transaction'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.base.BaseDependencies.Repository.TransactionRepo.findByFromAccount(com.base.BaseDependencies.Models.Account)! No property 'fromAccount' found for type 'Transaction'
```

Transaction Model

```
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Transactions")
    public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="trans_id",updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int transId;

    private String transType;
    
    private double transAmount;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_number")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Account fromAcct;
    
    private long toAcct;


}
```

Transaction Repo

```
     @Repository
     public interface TransactionRepo extends CrudRepository<Transaction, Integer> {

         List<Transaction> findByFromAccount(Account fromAccount);

}
```

ive tried changing the name of the method and also the parameter type that is passed to it but i still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property names used in the repository need to match those in your entity.
The error message says: `No property 'fromAccount' found for type 'Transaction'`
And if you check your entity, this is true. There is only a property `fromAcct`.

Therefore the repository method should be named `findByFromAcct`

Comment: Ok thank you I've tried this and it worked!!!!